# Representing a fraction as a $p$-adic number

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

If we have the following $p$-adic number:

$$2+3p+5p^2+2p^3+3p^4+5p^5+2p^6+3p^7+5p^8+.....$$  and I am trying to find what rational number this p-adic number represents. I have no idea as to how to go about doing this. The only thing that I can notice is that maybe we need to split this up into cases where $p<5$ and $p\geq 5$ because otherwise this is some non-standard representation.

Cheers

Comment: group the terms in threes, and note that each group is $p^3$ times the preceding group. So you have a geometric series, with ratio $|p^3|\,<\,1$. From here on, you do it just as you did in high school.

Comment: multiply it by $p^3-1$ and tell us what happens.

Comment: thanks, if we sum that geometric sum we get $-\frac{(2+3p+5p^2)}{p^3-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a geometric progression,
$$Sum = (2+3p+5p^2)(1+p^3+p^6+...)=\frac{2+3p+5p^2}{1-p^3}$$